# Save user bot conversation along with Intent in MS Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm creating a MS composer bot using in c#. Can I know how to save the user input, bot response and intent triggered in  Sql server DB.

Should I make use of ${turn} object in composer to save the details by making an Http request for each and every turn or is there any way to save? and even I didn't find any activity or turn object in backend to make use of it. Can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The documentation on [writing to storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and [saving user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) might be a good place to start. Though they describe how you can save to CosmosDB or Blobs, you can use the code samples to understand how to extract data from the conversation that you might want to save.

Comment: @AP01 thanks for the response, I was looking into the reference you shared but I observed that even they are using turnContext object to store the details. But In composer backend code I haven't found any such object everything is taken care by `adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs on [conversation flow and memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-memory?tabs=v2x) in Composer, and specifically the [default memory scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/ref-memory-variables?tabs=v2x) (such as `turn.activity.text`, which gets the message's text content). These documents show the scope values needed to extract data about the conversation and each turn. They are akin to the `turnContext` scope you see in code-first bots.

There is no default method to store information in a SQL database, however you have a few options.

- You could use HTTP requests as you suggested, but this wouldn't be a particularly speedy solution (depending on how you implement it of course), so I wouldn't necessarily recommend it.
- You could look into [extending Composer with code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-extend-with-code) and build a small addition that would store conversation data into a SQL DB as per your schema.
- You could try to use this [SqlClient](https://github.com/tomlm/iciclecreek.bot/tree/master/source/Libraries/Iciclecreek.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Database.SqlClient) package for Composer (available through the nuget package manager in Composer itself). It was written by a Bot Framework developer.